# where is ns-2.35 and tcl8.5.8 directories in file system stored?

Tags: ns2

I used `sudo apt-get install ns2` to install `ns2`. I want to know where are the above mentioned directories stored on my system?

Comment: `dpkg-query --listfiles ns2`

Comment: `$ dpkg -L ns2` ... or read the on-line file list(s) : https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/ns2/filelist ... Ref. the search page https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ns2